# Sending out email alert during business days

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I have a process builder set up which send email alert in scheduled Action. I send an email alert after 14 days of record been created.

I want to send email alerts after 14 business days and not just 14 days. Is there a way to achieve this using process builder or Visual work flow? I do not want to use Apex since I will hit the daily limit of 1000 email that can be sent out using Mass email/ single email messaging class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a before trigger or invocable apex to calculate the date and then send the email based on that.

Comment: As a point of clarity, if you are sending emails to contacts the 1000 daily limit does not apply. That limit is to external addresses (plain email addresses not contact ids). Adrian's comment is they way to go but just thought I should mention.

Comment: sorry I did not mention the email address are external ids and not contacts. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Can you give me an idea of how I can go about this? I have to send email alert after 14 days from the date record was ceated. If the 14th day is Saturday/Sunday then I should send the email on Tuesday( Not Monday).

Comment: I figured for my requirement , the solution can be achieved by using a formula field and referring it in Process builder scheduled action.

Answer (score -1):

Here the formula field to find business days.  this might help for your requirement.
CASE(MOD( SLAExpirationDate__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 
0 , CASE( MOD( End_Date__c - SLAExpirationDate__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
1 , CASE( MOD( End_Date__c - SLAExpirationDate__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
2 , CASE( MOD( End_Date__c - SLAExpirationDate__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
3 , CASE( MOD( End_Date__c - SLAExpirationDate__c,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
4 , CASE( MOD( End_Date__c - SLAExpirationDate__c,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
5 , CASE( MOD( End_Date__c - SLAExpirationDate__c,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
6 , CASE( MOD( End_Date__c - SLAExpirationDate__c,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
999) 
+ 
(FLOOR(( End_Date__c - SLAExpirationDate__c)/7)*5)

Find more info here. 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004526